# GameMaker Studio 2 random isnt random

Tags: game-design, game-maker, random

I'm making a game where things randomly generate. It used to work, but now all the sudden they keep spawning in the same area every time. does anybody know a fix?

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `randomize` to set the seed to a random value

More here: https://docs.yoyogames.com/source/dadiospice/002_reference/maths/real%20valued%20functions/randomize.html